# How to use generics in a Map with values of different types

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic `Command` interface:

```
public interface Command<T> {
    public void execute(T value);
}
```

And some implementations:

```
public class ChangeName implements Command<String>{
    public void execute(String value) {...}
}
public class SetTimeout implements Command<Integer>{
    public void execute(Integer value) {...}
}
```

What I need is a `Map` to link command names with a specific `Command` object:

```
Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<>();
...
commands.put("changeName", new ChangeName());
```

Obviously, I am getting `rawtypes` warnings when declaring the `Map`. 
If I use a question mark I end up with a compilation error:

```
Map<String, Command<?>> commands = new HashMap<>();
...
commands.get("changeName").execute("Foo"); // -> compilation error
```

> The method execute(capture#2-of ?) in the type Command is not applicable for the arguments (String)

I know that you cannot have a typesafe heterogeneous container with a non-reifiable type (**Item 29** in *Effective Java*), but what is the best approach to address this problem?

Comment: Why not to create map of string commands, map of integer commands, etc...? Or you can create only string commands with argument parsing....

Comment: @matoni Yes, that is an option.Given the name of the command (e.g. "changeName") I would have to look for it in every map to find the matching Command object.

Comment: In compilation error line you know that you only will consider commands that accept a String rather than a Integer at compilation time. Is this always the case? Can the type be stablished at compilation time. If so it makes more sense to have a different hash per type, and draw from the one you need depending on your argument type.

Comment: @ValentinRuano No. What I get as input is the name of the command ("changeName") and an `Object` as value ("Foo" or 3 or even a Map)

Comment: In that case I suggest that you improve your code a bit ... instead of passing "Foo" you should pass an Object of unknown type... perhaps enclosing the call into a method that accepts the Object as a argument.

Comment: In this case you must address this in run-time... command would need to keep a reference to the types of arguments that they can handle and an appropriate informative exception should be thrown if a wrong type argument is passed to them. This check could be done when execute is called or a "casting" operation between the map get and execute.

Comment: @ValentinRuano So you mean making `Command` interface no generic and using `Object` as a type in the `execute` method, don't you? And then check and casting the type in the `execute` method itself.

Comment: Please find my anwer below.

Comment: Please quote the compilation error, for the benefit of future readers of the question.

Comment: @slim Error message added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make the Commands aware of their acceptable argument at run-time:

```
public abstract class Command<T> {
    private final Class<T> argumentClass;

    protected Command(Class<T> argumentClass) {
        this.argumentClass = argumentClass;
    }

    public abstract <U extends T> void execute(U argument);


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public final <U> Command<? super U> cast(Class<U> argumentClass) {
        if (this.argumentClass.isAssignableFrom(argumentClass)) {
           return (Command<? super U>) this;
        } else {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException("this command cannot handle argument of type " + argumentClass.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Now the using code would be something like this:

```
private <U> void executeCommand(final String name, final U arg) {
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     Class<U> clazz = (Class<U>) arg.getClass();
     commands.get(name).cast(clazz).execute(arg);
}
```

The suppress-warning above is an annoying one as that cast must always be true but is a limitation of the final definition of `getClass` as returning `Class<?>`.

The map could be typed as:

`Map<String, Command<?>> commands = new HashMap<>();`

And each command subtype class would extend of the abstract `Command` class.

For example an anonymous inner class definition o a print string command to stderr:

```
final Command<String> printString = new Command<String>(String.class) {
    public <U extends String> void execute(U arg) {
        System.err.println(arg);
    }
};
```

The standalone version:

```
public StdErrPrintCommand extends Command<String> {

     public StdErrPrintCommand() { super(String.class); }

     @Override
     public <U extends String> void excecute(U arg) { 
            System.err.println(arg);
     }
}
```

If you prefer you could extract an `Command` interface and rename the abstract class as `AbstractCommand`.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it logically, what is that highest common interface which all your command template have to satisfy?

Looking at your example of String, Integer, it seems like it can't be anything but Java Object. Try this,

```
Map<String, Command<? extends Object>> commands = new HashMap<>();
```

**Edit**:
Basically, you are adding template information while declaring but would want to completely erase it while using it. There are two options here:

a) You don't use generics because you are not able to use them to their potential. Deal with simple Object class instead and in your specific execute functions just test for the right types.

b) Create different maps for different types. This way you would be able to use templates to their potential.

Comment: How would you implement getting the command and invoking the execute method?