# Java generic capture cannot be applied to extends with Factory pattern

Tags: java, generics, interface, factory

I have an abstract LogEvent class and I have Partitioner interface for that class. So `X extends LogEvent`  and `Y implements Partitioner<X>` and I store this mapping in an object so that I can get the appropriate partitioner class in runtime by a simple lookup. I am only writing the relevant parts.

Partitioner is only applied to LogEvent nothing else

```
public interface Partitioner<T extends LogEvent> {
    List<Partition> getPartitions(T event);
```

It partitions X type of LogEvents

```
public class XPartitioner implements Partitioner<X>
```

This holds the mapping, it also has a default value, not shown here.

```
public class PartitionerFactory {
    public PartitionerFactory register(Class<? extends LogEvent> clazz, Partitioner<? extends LogEvent> partitioner) {
        partitionerMap.put(clazz, partitioner);
```

Registering works

```
PartitionerFactory partitionerFactory = // ...
Partitioner<? extends LogEvent> partitioner = new XPartitioner();
partitionerFactory.register(X.class, partitioner);
```

However, this gives an error

```
LogEvent event = // Fetched from somewhere
Partitioner<? extends LogEvent> partitioner = partitionerFactory.get(event.getClass());
List<Partition> partitions = partitioner.getPartitions(event);
```

This fails, gives the following error:

```
capture<? extends LogEvent> in Partitioner cannot be applied to LogEvent
```

If I change the register and get to `Partitioner<LogEvent>` get works but now the register fails with same reason. What am I missing & doing wrong?

**Edit:**  I have added the following and it works for register and get:

```
<T extends LogEvent> List<Partition> getPartitions(T event);
```

However, now my XPartitioner needs to implement this function:

```
public <T extends LogEvent> List<Partition> getPartitions(T event)
```

I am really confused.

**Edit 2:**
If I change the signature to the following, It works however, it gives a warning of "Unchecked assignment" since the underlying object is `Partitioner<LogEvent>`

```
public PartitionerFactory register(Class<? extends LogEvent> clazz, Partitioner partitioner) {
```

Comment: Dont use generic in that case - `get` will return **unknown** class thus assignment is invalid.

Comment: I think this should help you: [How to use generics in a Map with values of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48155477/how-to-use-generics-in-a-map-with-values-of-different-types#answer-48157089)